# Makefile: Rules for multiple directories and files differentiated by a string pattern

Tags: r, makefile, rstudio

I have a Makefile rule in an RStudio project that builds various intermediate and output data files. Some of the key rules look like this:

```
outdir/<location>/outdata_<location>.file: script.R datadir/<location>/indata_<location>.file
    $(EXEC) $< <location>
```

where `location` differentiates directories as well as the filenames of both targets and prerequisites, and **at the same time is passed as an argument** to `script.R`.

Pictorially, this is how, for example, the prerequisites' directories are structured:

```
datadir
|- location1
|  |- indata_location1.file 
|  |- ...
|
|- location2
|  |- indata_location2.file 
|  |- ...
|
|- location3
```

Each of these directories have different levels of data files, hence the decision to organise them by location. Also, more project locations are added over time, hence the need for implicit rules to minimize the need for constant tinkering with the Makefile.

I've tried using pattern rules as described in the GNU Make documentation but it says the pattern placeholder can only appear once in either target or the prerequisite(s). I tried using string manipulation and the `foreach` functions but have not been able to solve it as my experience with GNU Make is limited.

I've seen similar SO questions on multiple directories but none that refer to use of the differentiating string as an argument in the recipe.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use several very similar rules, and the variance is too complicated for a pattern rule. This looks like a job for [a "canned recipe"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes).

We write a template:

```
define data-rule
outdir/$(1)/outdata_$(1).file: script.R datadir/$(1)/indata_$(1).file
    $(EXEC) $$< $(1)
endef
```

(The exact syntax varies with different versions of Make, so you may need '=' at the end of the "define" line.)

We can now generate the text of the `location1` rule with [`call`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Call-Function):

```
$(call data-rule,location1)
```

and have Make interpret that text as actual makefile code with [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function):

```
$(eval $(call data-rule,location1))
```

Once we verify that this much works, we can generate the rules one by one:

```
$(eval $(call data-rule,location1))
$(eval $(call data-rule,location2))
$(eval $(call data-rule,location3))
```

or use [`foreach`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function):

```
LOCATIONS := location1 location2 location3
$(foreach loc,$(LOCATIONS),$(eval $(call data-rule,$(loc))))
```

Finally, you may want a target that builds all of these files:

```
all-locations: outdir/location1/outdata_location1.file outdir/location2/outdata_location2.file outdir/location3/outdata_location3.file
```

You can automate this construction too:

```
$(foreach loc,$(LOCATIONS),$(eval all-locations: outdir/$(loc)/outdata_$(loc).file))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I noticed that in the canned recipe, the reference to the first prerequisite has 2 dollar signs i.e. `$$<`. Why is this?

Comment: @BroVic: I'm not entirely sure, but it seems that automatic variables must be escaped like that, lest they be expanded too soon. Anyway, that's what seems to work in testing.